# Convert Json output to UTF8

Tags: php, json

Currently, I'm trying convert my JSON output to UTF8, I'm using `charset=utf-8` but still not working. I don't know why it's happening since I set charset to utf-8. Also, my `link` output contains `\`, like: `http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/freela\/music\/\/SERVER\/Titas - Epitafio.mp3`. How to avoid it?

You can check it here: http://ntcdn.stream/audio/abc.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
ini_set("display_errors", 1);


function getList() {
    $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]/";
    $log_directory = "SERVER/";
    $main_array = [];

    $i = 1;
    foreach(glob($log_directory.'*.*') as $file) {
        $file = str_replace($log_directory, "", $file);
        $file = str_replace(".mp3", "", $file);

        if (strpos(utf8_encode($file), '-') !== false) {
            $string = explode('-', utf8_encode($file));
            $desc = $string[0];
        } else {
            $desc = "";
        }

        $main_array[] = array(
            'id'=>$i,
            'name'=>$file,
            'description'=>trim($desc),
            'link'=>$actual_link.$log_directory.utf8_encode($file).'.mp3',
        );
        $i++;
    }
    $out = array_values($main_array);
    echo(json_encode($out)); 
}
getList();

?>
```

I hope that you understand what I'm trying to say here. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Karina, utf8_encode is often misunderstood (it doesn't really encode just to UTF8, it specifically converts FROM ISO-8559-1, which is a different encoding) & JSON is always UTF8. If it's not UTF-8, it's not JSON. Could you share a sample of what you hope to see, and what you're seeing instead? it will help pinpoint this.

Comment: Hi, check it: http://prntscr.com/kzj33j `Vou passar cerol na m\u00c3\u00a3o` should be `Vou passar cerol na mão` and `http:\/\/` should be `http://`. All `/` contains ` \ ` before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `json_encode($out)`, try:

```
json_encode(out, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE |  JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
```

See: https://secure.php.net/json_encode